# How to read date and time from an image file

Tags: java, image, datetime

How to exactly get a date and time from an image file (which was created) as a yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa, this is the code i am using.

```
Path p = Paths.get( "C:\\DowloadFolder\\2.png" );
BasicFileAttributes view = Files.getFileAttributeView( p, BasicFileAttributeView.class ).readAttributes();  

System.out.println( view.creationTime()+" is the same as "+view.lastModifiedTime() );
```

I tried to use `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy" );`, but dont know how to get date and time from an image file.

Comment: What is your question? How to extract a date-time from the metadata embedded in an image file? If so, why are you posting this code for getting date-time from file system?

Comment: I just want to get a date-time of image was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your Question Is Confusing

You seem to be asking for date-time when a file was created. But you also refer to some date format in your first sentence. And then you refer specifically to an image file which implies you want the metadata embedded in jpeg and some other image formats.

## Your Question Has Its Own Answer

If all you want is the creation time on a file, your example code in the question already has that information, a `java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime` object.

Here is some example code of my own to demonstrate.

```java
Path p = Paths.get( "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/johndoe/text.txt" );
BasicFileAttributes view = null;
try {
    view = Files.getFileAttributeView( p, BasicFileAttributeView.class ).readAttributes();
} catch ( IOException ex ) {
    Logger.getLogger( App.class.getName() ).log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
}

// As of Java 7, the NIO package added yet another date-time class to the Java platform.
java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime fileTimeCreation = view.creationTime();
java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime fileTimeLastModified = view.lastModifiedTime();
```

That `fileTimeCreation` object has your file's creation date-time information. Read [the doc](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html) on how to use it.

For use with other classes, you may want to convert to another kind date-time object. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). Avoid the old java.util.Date & Calendar classes bundled with Java as they are notoriously troublesome.

Do not forget the time zone. Usually better to specify a desired time zone than rely on default.

```
// Convert to Joda-Time.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( fileTimeCreation.toMillis(), timeZone );

// Convert to java.time.* package in Java 8.
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse( fileTimeCreation.toString() ).withZoneSameInstant( zoneId );

// Convert to java.util.Date
// Caution: I do not recommend using java.util.Date & Calendar classes. But if you insist…
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date( fileTimeCreation.toMillis() );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "fileTimeCreation: " + fileTimeCreation );
System.out.println( "fileTimeLastModified: " + fileTimeLastModified );
System.out.println( "Joda-Time dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "java.time zonedDateTime: " + zonedDateTime );
System.out.println( "java.util.Date (with default time zone applied): " + date );
```

When run…

```
fileTimeCreation: 2014-02-16T02:28:51Z
fileTimeLastModified: 2014-02-16T02:34:17Z
Joda-Time dateTime: 2014-02-16T03:28:51.000+01:00
java.time zonedDateTime: 2014-02-16T03:28:51+01:00[Europe/Paris]
java.util.Date (with default time zone applied): Sat Feb 15 18:28:51 PST 2014
```

Comment: sorry about confusing. Thank you for answering. I think where i did wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [metadata-extractor](http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/) which does the job.

More info can be found [here](http://www.geekcap.com/campus/Java/article/56).
Or [this one](https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/)

Comment: Is there any way not use library??

Comment: Yes. Make your own library for it. But why would you do *that*?

Comment: I already import jar file, but it still has a error for `Metadata`, `ImageMetadataReader`,`Directory`